# React рендер при фокусе на инпуте

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Можно ли в реакте рендерить только когда в инпуте есть фокус? и чтобы при исчезновении фокуса исчезал рендер? если можно то как?

Comment: Копайте в сторону `refs`, если внутри компонента. Если речь о базовом рендере, то непонятен вопрос ибо чистый js.

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте обработчик, который будет менять state родительского компонента.
Через props спустите его к вашему компоненту и в зависимости от true или false значения в пропсах осуществляйте рендер компонента или рендер пустой строки.

Опционально можно сделать через inline-стили и переключать visibility элемента.